# Keep user session of quickblox alive in android

Tags: android, session, quickblox, quickblox-android

Hello everyone i am working with http://quickblox.com/developers/Sample-webrtc-android its works fine

But i want know that is there any way to keep user logged in as quick blox user in my app.

Because right now everytime user open my app user have to login first so i want to keep session alive if it is possible android,

Because its better to do for performance instead of everytime login just prevent to login and keep session alive

Thanks in advance

I have used below code

```
private void createSession(final String login, final String password) {

    final QBUser user = new QBUser(login, password);
    QBAuth.createSession(login, password, new QBEntityCallbackImpl<QBSession>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(QBSession session, Bundle bundle) {
            Log.d(TAG, "onSuccess create session with params");
            user.setId(session.getUserId());

            if (chatService.isLoggedIn()) {
                initQBRTCClient();

            } else {
                chatService.login(user, new QBEntityCallbackImpl<QBUser>() {

                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess() {
                        Log.d(TAG, "onSuccess login to chat");
                        /*
                         * ListUsersActivity.this .runOnUiThread(new
                         * Runnable() {
                         * 
                         * @Override public void run() {
                         * showProgress(false); } });
                         * 
                         * startCallActivity(login);
                         */
                        islogin = true;
                        initQBRTCClient();
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onError(List errors) {

                        Toast.makeText(HomeAppActivity.this, "Error when login", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        for (Object error : errors) {
                            Log.d(TAG, error.toString());
                        }
                    }
                });
            }

        }

        @Override
        public void onError(List<String> errors) {
            Toast.makeText(HomeAppActivity.this, "Error when login, check test users login and password",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As described in [documentation](http://quickblox.com/developers/Android#A_couple_of_words_about_Authentication_and_Authorization) session token is valid for 2 hours.

Once you have logged, you can store session token & expiration time somewhere in app storage - preference, database, etc. Token can be retrieved by  `BaseService.getBaseService().getToken().` 
When user opens your app again, you can set session using stored token `BaseService.createFromExistentToken()`

Here is the [documentation](https://sdk.quickblox.com/android/).
Also to keep running permanently chat connection it’s better to use [android service](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html).

Comment: will you please explain more

Comment: Hey, Kishan Soni, did you found any solution?